# android - OutOfMemoryError while downloading data using Volley library

Tags: android, caching, out-of-memory, android-volley

FATAL EXCEPTION:

While downloading data using `volley library` it throws `OutOfMemoryError`. I tried to clear volley chahing

```
AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(tag_json_obj);
            AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(tag_json_obj, true);
```

But still getting this error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                       at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:255)
                                                                       at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:228)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:66)
                                                                       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:116)
```

Comment: looks like your JSON is innormously large. Do you know how large is it?

Comment: Yes its really large , can someone tell me why you gave negative vote to my Question?

Comment: That was not me, but I think it was because you didn't give any detiles on the question, and all we could do is just guess. I guessed the most obvious thing.

Comment: Yes miight be
but its just a simple question related to VOlley which throws me the OutOfMemoryError I just need help.

Comment: Ok, I'm here to help. So your JSON is really large, right? but How large? what is it's size?

Comment: yes @VladMatvienko you are right its because of large json. The size of the json is 3.07MB\

Comment: Ok. Don't you have a pagination feature on the backend? so it gives you the content partially?

Comment: No pegination is not featured from server side but I think I must use this.

Comment: you can't use it if server doesn't support it

Comment: Sorry I mean to say backend logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 and a half day I have just put the below string in menifest file and it solves my crashing issue.

```
<application
    ....
       android:largeHeap="true">
```